# How do I wrap EJBAccessException for webservice consumers?

Tags: java, web-services, security, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0

Consider this simple example:

```
@Stateless
@WebService
public class AccountService {

  @WebMethod
  @RolesAllowed("CUSTOMER")
  public void replenishBalance(double amount) {
    //
  }

  @WebMethod
  @RolesAllowed("BOSS")
  public void emptyBankAccounts() {
    //
  }
}
```

If role authorization fails, EJB container will throw `EJBAccessException`  without entering any of these methods. Exception will be wrapped by webservice stack, finally resulting in a sort of *"javax.ejb.EJBAccessException: Client not authorized for this invocation"* to be shown in consumer's stacktrace.

Nevertheless these two are business methods (at least the first one), calling them wrongly is a business case too, and I expect to be able to make them throwing declared `@WebFault` exception, so that webservice consumer will be able to handle security exceptions too.

Is that possible?

PS: running Glassfish 3.1.2, Metro WS Stack